# Error decoding data with Codable even though parameters are optional

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, codable

I have the following `struct`:

```
struct Recipe: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var minutes: Int?
    
    init(id: String, minutes: Int) {
        
        self.id = id
        self.minutes = minutes
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        enum DecodingKeys: CodingKey {
            case minutes
          }
        
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DecodingKeys.self)
        minutes = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .minutes)
    }
}
```

I'm decoding from a source where `minutes` is null, so I get the following error message:

```
Error parsing response data: keyNotFound(DecodingKeys(stringValue: "minutes", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key DecodingKeys(stringValue: \"minutes\", intValue: nil) (\"minutes\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

However, I thought marking `minutes` as **optional** in `struct Recipe` was sufficient to handle this case? Is there something else I need to implement?

Comment: `container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .minutes)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "And a property being optional isn’t relevant here" It is totally relevant. This determines how he would need to implement a custom decoder which doesn't seem necessary at all in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement `init(from:)` manually you need to use the `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` variant for optional properties. The `decode(_:forKey:)` method throws an error if a nullable field in the JSON data is absent whereas the `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` method just returns nil.

Try this:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    enum DecodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case minutes
      }

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DecodingKeys.self)
    minutes = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .minutes)
}
```

Comment: The other option would be to not use a custom decoder, in which case the synthesised one will return `nil` for any optional property not present in the JSON.  This is the behaviour you expected, but by writing a custom decoder you "overwrite" this default behaviour and will need to implement yourself (as in the answer)